# How to permanently disable logging in JBoss 7/EAP6?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

Current application what to use its own log4j dependency, but this become a challenge to deploy on JBoss EAP6/AS7 as it always roll back the deployment due to logging issue.

So I follow some instructions online using following command

```
standalone.sh -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

good news is it works. Now I can deploy the application without error stopping the deployment.

Sad part is I cannot persuade the client to always start the server with such condition.

So my question is, how to make such change permanently within the application?

I try add

```
<exclusions>
    <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
    <module name="org.jboss.as.logging" /> <!--Including this trouble guy-->
    <module name="org.slf4j" />
</exclusions>
```

But it's not working....So what can I do ?

Comment: The `org.jboss.as.logging` module is not a dependency to your deployment. It does however look for configuration files within your deployment and attempt to configure logging for your deployment based on that configuration. The `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false` is that property that disables that behavior. What were the errors you were seeing?

Comment: @James R Perkins Thank you, here is the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682293/log4j-not-really-excluded-in-jboss-eap6-as7?noredirect=1#comment24029202_16682293

Comment: Ha, I commented on that one too :)

Comment: James same issue here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these lines to **standalone.xml** or **domain.xml**:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment" value="false"/>
</system-properties>
```

You could (**recommended**) do that via CLI interface. To do so, follow these steps:

1. cd  JBOSS_HOME/bin/
2. /jboss-cli.sh
3. connect
4. /system-property=org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment:add(value=false). Output: {"outcome" => "success"}

You should see applied these changes in your standalone.xml or domain.xml.

Hope it helps!